# How to show the completeness of the space of Fourier transforms $\mathcal{F}L^{1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Consider the space of all [Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of $L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ that is,
$$\mathcal{F}L^{1}=\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R):= \{f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R):\hat{f}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)\},$$
with the norm, $\|f\|_{\mathcal{F}(L^{1})}=\|\hat{f}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}.$
(By uniqueness theorem and using the fact that Fourier transform is a linear, one can deduce that, this is actually a norm)

> **My Question**: How to show $\mathcal{F}L^{1}$ is a complete with respect to the above norm ?

**My attempt**: Suppose $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{F}L^{1},$
that is, there is $N\in \mathbb N$, such that, $\|\hat{f_{n}}-\hat{f_{m}}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$, for every $n, m \geq N$; and since $(L^{1}(\mathbb R), \|\cdot\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)})$ is complete, there is a $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$, such that, $\|\hat{f_{n}}-g\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ We must find,  $h\in \mathcal{F}L^{1}$ such that $\|f_{n}-h\|_{\mathcal{F}L^{1}}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Now my guess work is that, we should take, $h:=\check{g}$; but then the problem is: can we expect, $\hat{h}=g$ (I know this one can expect, if both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ both are in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$, by inversion formula); or am I missing some thing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you understand the line
$$\mathcal{F}L^1 = \{f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R):\hat{f}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)\} \tag{1}$$
What does it mean to take the Fourier transform of an $L^\infty$ function? Obviously, the integral defining the transform has no reason to converge.

*Version 1.* What you actually mean is 
$$\mathcal{F}L^1 = \{\check g : g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)\} \tag{2}$$
(Since $\check g$ is automatically in $L^\infty$, I do not include this as a condition.)

Then your proof works as is. There is not much to prove, actually. The correspondence $g\mapsto \check g$ is an isometry from $L^1$ onto $\mathcal{F}L^1$, and isometries preserve completeness.

*Version 2.* Every element   $f\in L^\infty$ is a tempered distribution; we know how to take Fourier transform of those. The transform  $\hat f$ is in general a tempered distribution, but if it happens to be represented by an $L^1$ function, then we say $f\in \mathcal{F}L^1$.

In this version you need to know that the inversion formula works for tempered distributions. But this is a lot easier than it sounds: all we do is pass hats from distributions to test functions, and since test functions are all in $L^1\cap \mathcal FL^1$, inversion works.